# Help me unlock my bike

Tags: mathematics

I have a nice mountain bike, which I use on a daily basis. I always lock my bike.

Today, I awoke and to my surprise the bike was stolen. It startled me because it is locked with a really expensive combination lock. I walked around the vicinity and found it lying still locked in a shrubbery. Apparently, someone must have carried it away, tried to break the lock open in a more quieted neighbourhood but failed to do so.

I need to unlock my bike in order to ride it (duh). The trouble is that two of the four wheels with the numbers present on them have been removed. I can still turn the wheels, but I do not know which number I'm "entering" as a combination.

However, I have noticed that there are two cavities in the underlying smooth wheels with no numbers on them. I know for a fact that these cavities are present on the same numbers, but I can't tell them apart and do not know under which number the cavities were initially.

**Artists Impression:**

*(Note: The two cavities are under the same number, but I don't know whether it is `2` or any other number, I just had to draw the cavities somewhere...)*

[image]

My combination is `4 2 7 0`

I can enter `4 2`, but I do not know the other two numbers I'm entering it. I can unlock my lock in $10^2$ trials, but using the additional information I can't help but think that I could need even less trials.

### Optional Bonus

If that is too easy, try and solve the problem for $n$ additional wheels.

Comment: The funny thing is the the exact same thing did in fact happen to me. (Hint to the thieves: No, the combination of my new lock isn't `4270`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the information that the cavities mark the same number to

> rotate the last two wheels relative to each other such that their distance is 7 steps (first wheel 7 steps further than secon wheel). Then you rotate them together through the $10$ possible positions (or until the lock is opened). If the lock doesn't unlock, you did it with the wrong combination of cavities. In that case you need another $10$ steps for the other combination. This gives a total of $20$ steps (at most).

In the case of $n$ additional wheels it works in a similar way:

> 1. First, pick a random cavity in each of the wheels and assume it marks the number `0`. Under this assumption, enter your code. If this doesn't open your lock, rotate all $n$ wheels by 1 until you tried all $10$ possible orientations.
>
>    After that, you need to account for the fact, that all wheels have 2 indistinguishable cavities, that means that relative to the $1$st wheel you can switch the cavity that is assumed to be `0` to the opposite cavity on each of the other $n-1$ wheels. This gives a total of $2^{n-1}$ possible permutations of cavity assignments. 
>     For each assignment permutation you have to:
>
>    1. Enter your code.
>
>       Repeat the $10$ rotation steps.
>
>    Continue switching the `0`-assigned cavity and try $10$ rotation steps until you tried all $2^{n-1}$ possible permutations of cavity assignments.
>
> Like this you need at most $10 \cdot 2^{n-1}$ attempts instead of $10^n$.

Comment: There are two cavities on each wheel however, and I don't know which one is which.

Comment: @Narusan Oh you're right. I've edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: Yes, it is given that they are on the opposite side. // Okay, that was too easy. I found the incident funny and decided to share it here. If you want to, go for the optional bonus for a more complex problem. // What is the site policy, should I immediately accept a right answers (other sites like PPCG have a policy of not accepting answers too early).

Comment: @Narusan Usually one accepts an answer if you don't expect a better one. But you can also accept a newer answer, if it is better.

Comment: @Narusan I've improved the explanations and also clarified the maximal number of steps. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 9):

> I know for a fact that these cavities are present on the same numbers

Which implies that

> The markings were made by the manufacturer, and exist below the same number on the other wheels as well.  Therefore, we can learn what number the marking represents by taking note as we remove the numbers from one of the other wheels.

Comment: I‘d still have $2^3$ solutions to check and an even further damaged lock for the future. But yes - while not being the intended solution - this is a solution as well, in a way.

Comment: @Narusan By this method, you figure out which number the marking corresponds to.  As such, you can just turn the wheels to their proper place.  You're going to keep using the lock?

Comment: Yes, I will keep using the real lock. The other answer yields me the number the marking corresponds to as well - once I have solved the combination - and for the future it will be only two wheels with less markings. // The reason why I liked the puzzle is that it shows how seemingly mundane information can lead to a drastic decrease in required trials ($10*2^n$ vs $10^n$). Your solution is also a solution, it’s just not the „desired“ one, but I appreciate the lateral thinking. Maybe I should point out that using the accepted approach I had already unlocked my bike prior to posting here, it was

Comment: [cont‘d] afterwards that I have written this post and considered general cases for the problem.

Comment: "I'd still have $2^3$ solutions to check" Why?  If you discover that the digit over the cavity is, say, 2, then you would know that the one "above" the cavity is 1, and so on.  So you would know all the digits on the three wheels with no digit labels.  So it would take you only one try to open the lock.

Comment: As the number of wheels increases, I bet this solution gets more and more attractive.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I still don’t know which cavity is which, so I‘m left with 2 „digits“ per wheel (cavity one and cavity two) and three wheels.

Comment: Oh, I see, the two cavities per wheel represent two different digits.  Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Narusan This is now confusing.  The accepted answer works if there is one cavity on each wheel, and both cavities mark the same number.  The accepted answer takes ten tries at worst, regardless of how many wheels there are.  Now you're saying that there are two cavities per wheel.  If that's true, then the accepted answer is wrong, it would take 20 tries.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I don't think that's correct... This is a confusing question all of the sudden.

Comment: @Carl Let‘s suppose that a 3 and an 8 are present on the two cavities on each wheel and you find that out after removal of the numbers. You can’t tell the cavities apart, so you need to check all combinations at worst.

Comment: @Narusan Then the accepted answer is wrong

Comment: @Carl How? The correct answer lists $20$ (2 times ten) and $10*2^n$ (where n is the number of wheels - 1)

Comment: @Carl See The clarification of the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

> Let's assume that left wheel is already set to 7 (like if the cavity was at 7), turn second wheel 7 positions down to get needed offset. Not open yet? Turn both wheels down (or up), repeat 10 times until unlocked.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it has already been posted

Comment: You need to do this 20 times (as the accepted answer shows) because you can’t tell cavities apart.

Comment: Yup, I've noticed that after posting, sorry :)

Comment: @Narusan why do you need to tell cavities apart? You know the combination, you know that cavities are at the same number, and you know the direction of numbers, so you just set relative combination and then rotate all wheels as many times as there are numbers on the wheel.

Comment: But there are two exact same cavities on each wheel, so you don’t know whether cavity 1 corresponds to number 0 or the opposite number 5.

Comment: @Narusan Ah, I see what you mean. Apparently I didn't read the description careful enough, so didn't realize there were two cavities on each wheel. Yes, in this case it would require 10 * 2 ^ (n-1) tries